# ASP.NET MVC Ajax request fail with net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR during large data size

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I have an ajax call like following:

```
var base64String = "data:image/png;base64,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"
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("photoByte", base64String);
formdata.append("eventRecordID", eventRecordIDs);

$.ajax({
 url: "@Url.Action("UploadSignature", "JobList")",
 contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
 cache: false,
 type: "POST",
 data: formdata,
 processData: false,
 contentType: false,
 success: function (result) {
    alert("success")
},
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
}
});
```

Once I call the ajax, I open the network tab and the particular request is in the status of pending.
[image: Pending]

So, I just keep waiting for 5min until it shows the error just like the title, protocol error. Sometimes it also fails with another error which is net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.
[image]

Strange thing happen when I change the base64String to short string (1-100+ char) and it works like normal without waiting. 2930 char is too large for ajax? Is there any limit on POST json data?
I don't know what does the error means at all. Hopefully someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

By the way, below is the headers of the particular request.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the maximum length of content in a request (in bytes)

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" maxQueryString="32768"/>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

under <system.webServer> in web.config